# Обмен данными между JavaScript и PostgreSQL (БЕЗ node.js)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, postgresql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно "подружить" JS и PG?

На сколько я понимаю непосредственно из браузера без применения NodeJS такое не провернуть?! Но...

Что имеем:

1. Сайт с формами, из которых данные должны попадать в PG.

Всё написано на JS и логика обработки и работы с данными в формах тоже на нём.

2. Провернуть данную операцию с применением NodeJS возможности нет из-за закрытости системы!!!
3. Для реализации хотелок, видится связка php и JS, но возникает вопрос, можно ли JS'ом обрабатывать данные, а потом вызывать скрипт php для передачи сформированных данных.

Причём без учёта промежуточных звеньев хранения этих данных, т.е. без использования JSON.

Например, результаты работы JS поместить в скрипт php, который отправляет данные в БД. Тут можно использовать интерполяцию.

Но вот как быть с запросом данных из БД, которые получает php и аккуратно передаёт их JS для соответствующего их вывода на фронте?!

Рад буду ответам и светлым мыслям )))

Comment: Подойдет любой серверный язык, умеющий обращаться к PostgreSQL (ну будет вместо ноды тот же пхп, не важно). Общение фронта и сервера можно свести к передаче строк друг другу. А дальше все зависит от конкретики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расскажу вам о другом способе. Не стандартном. Нужно на сервер встроить Hasura Engine, использующий GraphQl и связать его с вашей POSTGRESQL бд. Это будет вашей заменой ноджсу, то есть кодить ничего не нужно, нужно просто настроить Hasura Engine.
Далее запросы будут происходить из фронта сразу к бэку, без внедрения ноджса.
Гайдов сделать это очень много.
пример запроса из фронта будет выглядеть примерно так

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    query: `{
      \n  posts{
      \n    id
      \n    info
      \n  }
      \n}`,
      variables: {}
  });
  
      var config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'url',
      headers: { 
          'hasura-admin-secret': 'pass', 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data : data
      };
  
      axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за этот ответ! Это САМЫЙ ПОНЯТНЫЙ во всём интернете пример использования хасуры (hasura). Без него я никак не мог понять, что в этой чёртовой схеме вообще не нужен парольк базе данных, а достаточно просто правильно написать URL. и всё работает, черт побери! двое суток я искал, как выполнить запрос, и не мог найти, пока не встретился с этим ответом!

Answer (score 0):

Можно посылать AJAX запросы на PHP файл и из него через глобальный массив $_GET или $_POST получать данные. Далее (в PHP файле) отправлять данные на БД и через echo выводить к примеру сообщение, что данные успешно отправлены. В JS когда отправляєтся AJAX запрос можно получить ответ от того же PHP файла без перезагрузки страницы. Советую почитать про AJAX + PHP .

Answer (score 0):

Мысли следующие. Что может js сделать по существу кросбраузерно и кросплатформенно  безопасно из браузера? Отправить данные (socket, XMLHttpRequest). Значит его нужно будет обработать. Вариант который вы желаете чтоб это был сам Postgres, но из коробки такого нет. Остаётся писать web сервер и вовсе не обязательно на node.js благо их не мало. Остаётся определится на чём вам предпочтительнее писать и наличие необходимых библиотек.